# How to Get selected checkbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot, microservices

I am doing angular-is and Spring boot program where I want to send my checkbox data as a input but I am getting error. please look once.

```html
I am doing angularjs and Spring boot program where i want to send my checkbox data as a input but i am getting error. please look once.

Here is the Angular-js code
---------------------------
**$scope.saveUser = function() {
$scope.locationArray=[];
angular.forEach($scope.locations,function(location){
<!--        alert(JSON.stringify(locations))        -->
if(!!location.isselected)$scope.locationArray.push(location);
});
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.locationArray));   
alert("Your Data is Submiting ! Are You Sure to Submit ?..")
$http.post("http://localhost:8765/user-api/user/saveAll",$scope.user).then(
function successCallback(response) {
console.log("User Successfully posted data");
},
function errorCallback(response) {
console.log("Your Form Submission is  failed");
}
);
};**
---------------------------

Here is the HTML Code
------------------------
<div class="form-group" >
Location:: 
<div ng-repeat="location in locations"> 
   <label>{{location.opreaterAreaName}}</label>
   <input type="checkbox"   class="form-check-input"  ng-model ="location.isselected">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your error?

Comment: Please Add Proper Function code and as well as error also

Comment: I want to send data using checkbox but it's saying Null value. Data is not passing from web page to function.  I think whenever in push some problem is there ... And functions and html code is already there please look once and help me. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

After Adding this. Problem resolved

$scope.user.locations=$scope.locationArray;